# iOS app to transfer images, photos to another phone via Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is there an app that can help me get connected to bluetooth in mobile phones manufactured by companies like nokia, samsunng, etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  You want to connect the iPhone 4 to other phones via bluetooth?  What do you want the phones to do once they are connected via bluetooth?

Comment: i want to transfer pictures, songs and messages. Is there a app for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iPhone 4 does not support the Bluetooth OPP profiles which you need for standard device to device transfers. All you have available are

- HFP (handsfree)
- PBAP (Phonebook access)
- A2DP (advanced audio distribution)
- AVRCP (av remote)
- PAN (Personal Area Network)
- HID (Human Interface)

Peer to peer comms are possible over BT but the app has to implement the protocol stack itself

Answer (score 0):

There is [word](https://twitter.com/cocoanutapps) out on a jailbroken app in development called Celeste that should be able to do that and is rumored to be release soon.
If you are still on iOS3 you could try [iBlueNova](http://www.ihackintosh.com/2010/02/ibluenova-download-is-available-on-cydia/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [iBlueNova](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibluenova/id581396992?mt=8); it is a commercial app that you have to pay for. Alternatively, you can jailbreak your iPhone and maybe then you can send pictures and files to other phones without needing a commercial app.

[image: iBlueNova screenshot from the App Store]